# Select the curent div that in hovering

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a landing page, and I used the same classes for these images
[image]

and this code here to toggle the text inside which image

```
$(".overlay").hide();

  $(".projects-img, this").mouseover(() => {
    $(".overlay, this").show();
  });

  $(".projects-img, this").mouseout(() => {
    $(".overlay").hide();
  });
```

html

```
<div class="hold-img">
    <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
    <div class="overlay">
        Full landing page, made mostly with CSS and some cool stuff, enjoy it.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
    <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">  
    <div class="overlay">
        Full landing page, made mostly with CSS and some cool stuff, enjoy it.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
    <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">                
    <div class="overlay">
        Full landing page, made mostly with CSS and some cool stuff, enjoy it.
    </div>
</div>
```

the thing is, when a hover under any img, the text at first img is activated, how can I only active the text inside the current img I'm hovering?

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: `, this` shouldn't be inside the quotes. `$(".projects-img", this)`

Comment: Perhaps that is missing something about ```this``` selector, but I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `this` in the event bindings. When selecting the corresponding overlay, you want the sibling of the image that was hovered. Using `this` in the selector is for finding a child element, not a sibling.

You can use jQuery's `.hover()` method to do mouseover and mouseout in a single call.

```js
$(".overlay").hide();

$(".projects-img, this").hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".overlay").show();
}, function() {
  $(".overlay").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do it without any JavaScript, just CSS. The selector `.projects-img:hover + .overlay` matches the `overlay` class immediately following a hovered `projects-img` class.

```css
.overlay {
  display: none;
}

.projects-img:hover + .overlay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hold-img">
  <img class="projects-img" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/empire-state-building-at-night-picture-id533998713?b=1&k=20&m=533998713&s=170667a&w=0&h=MYfmvpyj7Sr7ibb-c1e3X__Elvgdfurq3unYvENjd6A=" height="300px" width="350px" alt="my first web site">
  <div class="overlay">
    Full landing page, made mostly with css and some cool stufs, enjoy it.
  </div>
</div>
```